# Enumerator instead of constructor for class instantiation?

Tags: c++, constructor, enums, fltk

I have a struct `Color` with an enumeration `Color_type`. The constructor has an argument of type `Color_type`; `Fl_Color`, `FL_RED`and `FL_BLUE` are a class and constants from [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/):

```
struct Color {
    enum Color_type {
        red = FL_RED,
        blue = FL_BLUE,
        // et cetera
    };

    Color(Color_type cc) :c(Fl_Color(cc)) { }
private:
    Fl_Color c;
};
```

Another type has a member function to set the color, like this:

```
class Grid {
    void set_color(Color col) { lcolor = col; }
private:
    Color lcolor;
};
```

I would expect this function to be called like this:

```
my_grid.set_color(Color(Color::red));
```

i.e., call the constructor with the enumerator, like declared. However, it also works like this:

```
my_object.set_color(Color::red);
```

Why? Is this a legal shorthand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor allows implicit conversions from `Color_type` to `Color`. If you don't want to allow that, you need to make it `explicit`:

```
explicit Color(Color_type cc) :c(Fl_Color(cc)) { }
```

Comment: Ah, I've found it in the Standard: "Conversion by constructor" (12.3.1) - thanks!